# AWS RDS Master and Read Replica scaling vertically

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have a MYSQL RDS db.m4.large and Read Replica db.m4.large. I am going to scale the Master DB to db.m4.4xlarge tier. Do I need to upgrade the read replica too at same tier as I am worried about the cost will increase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed, when looking through the documentation for [create-db-instance-read-replica](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/rds/create-db-instance-read-replica.html) there is a flag named `--db-instance-class` with the following description.

> The compute and memory capacity of the read replica, for example, db.m4.large . Not all DB instance classes are available in all AWS Regions, or for all database engines. For the full list of DB instance classes, and availability for your engine, see [DB Instance Class](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Concepts.DBInstanceClass.html) in the Amazon RDS User Guide.
>
> Default: Inherits from the source DB instance.

This means that replicas can have a different instance class than the master nodes, it is worth pointing out for multi-az that each node will be the same instance size.